# Error running the FPDF class

Tags: yii2, fpdf

I am making a PDF emission code via FPDF. Conducting tests for localhost everything was ok, however using the code on my server the following error appears:

```
PHP Fatal Error – yii\base\ErrorException
Class 'FPDI' not found
```

Answer (score 1):

FPDI library does not contain namespaces therefore autoloading works via [autoload-classmap directive](https://github.com/Setasign/FPDI/blob/master/composer.json#L16-L23) in the composer.json.

Therefore make sure, that `vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php` contains `FPDI` declaration. In case it does not - make sure, that you have `setasign/fpdi` in the root composer.json, run `composer update` and check `vendor/setasign/fpdi` directory contents.

Answer (score 0):

Thank it worked, updating the same vendor file / composer / autoload_classmap.php that was on my local machine I managed to run the FPDI library.

Comment: So could you login with the primary account and mark the answer as correct? :)